# Iterate through html.action result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following ActionResult method in my Controller Class which returns posts:

```
public ActionResult Feed()
{
    List<Models.Post> posts = getPosts();
    return PartialView(posts);
}
```

How do I iterate through these results (creating a new div for each post).
I tried `@foreach (var item in Html.Action("Feed"))` but this didn't work.

### Update 3:

Here is all relevant code to this problem. I also stopt using a model for the posts and now directly use the `LinqToTwitter.Status` object.

FeedController.cs

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Feed()
    {
        return PartialView(GetStatuses());
    }

    private List<LinqToTwitter.Status> GetStatuses()
    {
        //Code to get tweets
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Feed";
}

<div class="FeedPage" id="FeedPage">

    <div class="FeedPosts" id="FeedPosts">
    @{
        Html.Action("Feed");
    }
    </div>

    <div class="FeedAlternatives">
        <div class="FeedAlternativeContent">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="FeedOptions hidden">

    </div>

</div>
```

Feed.cshtml

```
@model List<LinqToTwitter.Status>

<div class="FeedPosts" id="FeedPosts">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="FeedPost SocialUpdate">
            @*More divs for design*@
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Exception thrown on `Html.Action("Feed");` in Index.cshtml:
[image]

And corresponding webresult:
[image]

Comment: You need to iterate through your collection of `Post` in the `Feed.cshtml` view - `@foreach(var post in Model) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code `@foreach (var item in Html.Action("Feed"))` does not work the way you think it should.

`Html.Action("Feed")` will execute a `ActionResult` which can return a View (HTML), JSON, File etc etc... In your case it returns a `PartialView` meaning it returns you an HTML.

So how you code this is. In your main view add a this line of code where you want your divs.

```
@Html.Action("Feed")
```

Then with your current `ActionResult` as is

```
public ActionResult Feed()
{
    List<Models.Post> posts = getPosts();
    return PartialView(posts);
}
```

**Add a new partial view** into your project solution. This partial view must intake a `List<Post>` type model and then loop it.

Your Partial view name should be `Feed` and its content as below.

```
@model List<Model.Post>

@foreach (var post in Model){
  //post will be a instance of each Post object.
  <div>
  <h1> post.Header</h1>      // just an example
  </div>
}
```

Comment: This sollution throws a `HttpCompileException` on `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_Feed") }`

Comment: @MaikoKingma You need to call your `ActionResult` which will return a partial view and not directly call your partial view `_Feed`

Comment: This gives another exception `The partial view 'Feed' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.`

Comment: @MaikoKingma I am so sorry for the syntax.. you should actually do `Html.Action` I updated my answer

Comment: this returns a `HttpException` - `Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.` Is it correct that my `public ActionResult Feed()` method is in the Controller class for my main view?

Comment: @MaikoKingma the error might be due to different reasons. One quick check what you can do is to directly hit your ActionResult from URL and see what happens

Comment: @MaikoKingma your `Feed` Action must be in the same controller as of your main view with current syntax, else if it is in different controller you can specify the controller name in the `html.Action` syntax, As said the error occurs due to many reasons, is it possible to add the complete error so that its easy to point out the cause

Comment: @MaikoKingma Also make sure you dont have any `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost] ` attributes decorated on the ActionResult

Comment: @Reddy See Update 2 in question

Comment: I have changed a lot in my code so I will update my question over 3,5 hours when my school ends.

Comment: @MaikoKingma No problem, But I think you should be able to see the yellow screen error right now.. hit continue when you get the error.. it will show the complete details in your browser page

Comment: @Reddy The problem seems to be in `@foreach (var item in Model)` in my Feed.cshtml file. if i remove this line the page does load. Should I iteratie in a different way?

Comment: @Reddy I have updated the question with all code and errors/Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Model`.

In this case `Model` will be a collection of `Post` objects, and you have to iterate it.

Please try this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model){

}
```

In your `Feed` method from controler you passed a list of `Post` to your `PartialView`.

```
public ActionResult Feed()
{
    List<Models.Post> posts = getPosts();
    return PartialView(posts);
}
```

So, in top of `Feed.cshtml` partial view use this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Post>
```